# What's the function of `LOCK_SECTION_START` in linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm reading the linux kernel semaphore codes and found the following codes

```c
static inline void down(struct semaphore * sem)
{
    might_sleep();
    __asm__ __volatile__(
        "# atomic down operation\n\t"
        LOCK "decl %0\n\t"     /* --sem->count */
        "js 2f\n"
        "1:\n"
        LOCK_SECTION_START("")
        "2:\tlea %0,%%eax\n\t"
        "call __down_failed\n\t"
        "jmp 1b\n"
        LOCK_SECTION_END
        :"=m" (sem->count)
        :
        :"memory","ax");
}
```

Why should we put the `__down_failed` in other text section by LOCK_SECTION_START macro ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [answer](https://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/down).

It is used for instruction cache optimization.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you give more details about the answer here in case others find their way here?